# Solving a system of 242 linear inequalities with 9 variables using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, linear-programming

I have a system of 242 linear inequalities with 9 variables (x1,...,x9), like this:

```
0 <= f1(x1,...,x9) <= 20
0 <= f2(x1,...,x9) <= 20
...
0 <= f242(x1,...,x9) <= 20
```

With the constraint:

```
0 <= x1,...,x9 <= 30
```

How do I approach this using MATLAB code?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [linprog](https://de.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/linprog.html)

Comment: @sascha I read about linprog, but from what I see from the expression of the problem, there is no need for an objective function, so how do I skip the f?

Comment: Use a zero vector or any other (as you did not specify what possible solutions you are looking for).

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly answering your question. You could download GNU GLPK and Gusek Editor and try to model your requirements.

If MATLAB also support mathematical programming language like MathProg, GAMS then you could model your linear equations and solve without any objective function (as @sascha commented).

```
/* MathProg Example : With trivial inequalities  */

param m, integer, > 0, default 242;
param n, integer, > 0, default 9;
set INEQUALITIES := 1..m;
set VARS := 1..n;
var x{j in VARS}, >= 0, <= 30;

s.t. phi{i in INEQUALITIES}: i - sum{j in VARS} x[j]  <= 20;

solve;

for{j in VARS} {
        printf"x[%2d] = %2d\n", j, x[j];
}

end;
```

Internally generated equations would look like:

```
Minimize
 obj: 0 x(1)

Subject To
 phi(1): - x(1) - x(2) - x(3) - x(4) - x(5) - x(6) - x(7) - x(8) - x(9)
 <= 19
 phi(2): - x(1) - x(2) - x(3) - x(4) - x(5) - x(6) - x(7) - x(8) - x(9)
 <= 18
 phi(3): - x(1) - x(2) - x(3) - x(4) - x(5) - x(6) - x(7) - x(8) - x(9)
 phi(242): - x(1) - x(2) - x(3) - x(4) - x(5) - x(6) - x(7) - x(8)
 - x(9) <= -222

Bounds
 0 <= x(1) <= 30
 0 <= x(2) <= 30
 0 <= x(3) <= 30
 0 <= x(4) <= 30
 0 <= x(5) <= 30
 0 <= x(6) <= 30
 0 <= x(7) <= 30
 0 <= x(8) <= 30
 0 <= x(9) <= 30

End
```

On solving the model, solution would look like:

```
>C:\gusek\glpsol.exe --cover --clique --gomory --mir -m "vijay.mod"    
GLPSOL: GLPK LP/MIP Solver, v4.64
Parameter(s) specified in the command line:
 --cover --clique --gomory --mir -m vijay.mod
Reading model section from vijay.mod...
vijay.mod:17: warning: final NL missing before end of file
17 lines were read
Generating phi...
Model has been successfully generated
GLPK Simplex Optimizer, v4.64
242 rows, 9 columns, 2178 non-zeros
Preprocessing...
222 rows, 9 columns, 1998 non-zeros
Scaling...
 A: min|aij| =  1.000e+00  max|aij| =  1.000e+00  ratio =  1.000e+00
Problem data seem to be well scaled
Constructing initial basis...
Size of triangular part is 222
      0: obj =   0.000000000e+00 inf =   2.475e+04 (222)
    222: obj =   0.000000000e+00 inf =   0.000e+00 (0) 2
OPTIMAL LP SOLUTION FOUND
Time used:   0.0 secs
Memory used: 0.5 Mb (538071 bytes)
x[ 1] = 30
x[ 2] = 30
x[ 3] = 30
x[ 4] = 30
x[ 5] = 30
x[ 6] = 30
x[ 7] = 30
x[ 8] = 12
x[ 9] =  0
Model has been successfully processed
>Exit code: 0    Time: 0.212
```